# Copy all attributes of a polyline in a layer to a different polyline in the same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

How do I copy all the attributes of a polyline in the attribute table represented by a row to a different polyline in a different row in the attribute table?

[image]

In the above figure, all the attributes of ID 1301 has to be copied and pasted to ID 1388.

Comment: nice and dirty way... copy and paste 1301 (creating duplicate). marge the created polygon with 1388. then edit and remove duplicated area...  did I mention time consuming?  I am sure there is some more efficient way.

Answer (score 6):

This is the quickest solution so far.

In the Editing mode.

Select and copy the attributes in the Attributes Tab.

[image]

Paste the attribute to the target entity.

[image]

Later delete the one that you dont want.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't now this tip after years of using arcgis :D

Answer (score 2):

You could merge both entities (via the Editor toolbar/menu) and keep the attributes of the upper one (make sure you are choosing the right one !).

[image: merge]

If multipart features is a problem, you can still single part it again after, it will recreate 2 rows with identical values.

[image: explode]

Comment: but these 2 entities have 2 different shape which I dont want to get merged. I want the one of the shape to be deleted.

Comment: The solution from @pnkjmndhl is the best then :)