# Copy Multiple (not all) attributes of a polyline to multiple polylines of same feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, fields-attributes

I have multiple fields in a feature. I need to copy multiple (5-6) attributes of a polyline to a different polyline in the same feature. To make things worse, I will have around 30 different polyline to copy the attributes to.

In [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234978/copy-all-attributes-of-a-polyline-in-a-layer-to-a-different-polyline-in-the-same/234988#234988), I found copying of all attributes of a polyline to a different polyline. The only difference is that, I need to copy specific (multiple) attributes of a polyline to multiple polylines in the same feature.

Comment: 5-6 attributes from a single polyline  to 30 others in the same feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this (maybe not the easiest way though) but be careful, you cant undo the changes:

Open the attribute table and select the single row you wish to copy from. Using the Python window execute this code to store the attributes in the variable attributes:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Points12345",['Field1','Field2','Field3']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        attributes=row
```

Clear the selection and then Select **only** the rows you wish to paste the attributes into and execute this code:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Points12345",['Field1','Field2','Field3']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row=attributes
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You need to change "Points12345" and the field names (and add/remove fields) to match your data.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: Since, I have to do it multiple times, I am trying to change your code to Script (with the name of the fields, source polyline, destination polylines as parameters). I will let you know if it does or doesnot work.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I combined both the codes to one. When I ran the code, the required attributes of the first selected polyline was copied to the rest.